# create() populates manytomany with every row in the related table, rather than leave it blank

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Currently, I have three models in models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass 

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    listings = models.ManyToManyField('Listing', related_name = "watchlists", blank = True)

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    description = models.TextField()
```

The problem occurs when a user creates their watchlist, which is handled by this piece of code in views.py:

```
# Each listing has it's own page,
# with a URL of the form /listing/<int:pk> 
def listing(request, pk):
    listing_instance = Listing.objects.get(pk = pk)
    
    if request.method == "GET":
         # return the page for the listing with primary key pk

    elif request.user.is_authenticated:   
        watchlist_instance = Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)[0]
        watchlist_instance.listings.add(listing_instance)
```

I would expect the row created by `Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)` to have no relations in its `listings`, but instead it has relations to every row in the Listing table (meaning the last line does nothing).

For example, if the Listing table contained three rows:

- listing1
- listing2
- listing3

and a new user viewed the page for listing2 and tried to add it to their watchlist, their watchlist would include all three listings.

To confirm it was `create()` that was causing the problem, I tried this:

```
    elif request.user.is_authenticated:
        watchlist_instance = listing_instance.watchlists.create(user = request.user)
```

which looks (to me) to be basically equivalent to the example given in the [official docs for create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.create), but has the same problem as my other code.

How can I ensure that `create()` leaves `listings` blank (so that I can then add the single `listing_instance` to it), rather than populating it with every listing in the table?

Edit: The problem persists even when creating the watchlist in Django's admin interface; the field is automatically populated with every `listing`. Also, there is no way to remove the relations, either by `clear()`, `remove()` or in the admin interface.

Django version 3.1.1

sqlite3

python 3.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is an idiot, this problem never existed.

I assumed that Django's admin page for a watchlist would only show the listings that were related, but it turns out it just shows every listing whether they're related or not.